# What will happen to session that was not destroyed/unset?

Tags: php

This may seem trivial.

What will happen to a session that was never destroyed/unset/write_close-d?
Lets just say I have set the session to never time out. What will happen to the session if person finds himself at the login page and logs in using different credentials. Also just for the testing purpose, the login page doesn't have redirect if session is set.

Will it overwritten and destroyed or never destroyed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your login sets all of the session variables, the session will be effectively destroyed by the new values.

If there is a variable that's in the session that *isn't* overwritten by the login, then it will persist.  The session is overwritten rather than destroyed and set again.

Comment: @TheHe Every variable is overwritten, thats not a problem. I just had a look at my session folder and there is a lot of sess_ files? Some of them are totally empty and some contain information about droppping the database... I guess thats phpmyadmin-s work...

Comment: maybe it's an indicator that you're beeing attacked? DROP-DATABASE is not a very most-used command ;)
you should set the session-lifetime to an appropiate level to keep the folder clean...
and double-check that you don't use any session-values, cookie-values, get-values or post-values unescaped in SQL-commands!

Comment: @TheHe Im not being attacked :D I used the drop database command from phpmyadmin multiple times, but it leaves big session files (26kB)...

Comment: okay ;) then you just modify your php-ini... maybe phpmyAdmin overrides the timeouting? (check this, too)
it's very common that your sessions-directory is completely filled up with junk ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sessions will be destroyed implicitly after timeout. The number of seconds for timeout can be specified in php.ini . Default is 1440 seconds or 24 minutes.

You have to set some arbitrarily large value for [session.gc-maxlifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) to seemingly never time out.

If you let someone else to go through the login process, it must overwrite the existing session. But all this ultimately depends on your code.

Comment: he says: "non timeouting" -- lifetime infinity

Answer (score 0):

if he logs in using different credentials with an already started session, the session will be simply overriden...
in the case, that the user deletes his cookies etc., a new session will be generated and the old one MAYBE will retain as session-file or in DB...
(depends on the php-settings)

Comment: I will have a look at the session folder to see whats going on.